# How to do collections-not for TDE with Marklogic

Tags: collections, marklogic, tde

I am looking to how to implement the collections-not for Marklogic TDE.

The equivalent one for the CTS query is

```
cts:not-query(cts:collection-query("archived"))
```

According to [TDE documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_30414), it only supports **AND**, **OR** collections. I am looking for **NOT** collections with TDE schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** I changed the sample from: *'.. = "include"..'* to *'... != "exclude"...'* They both work. However, for the context of the question, not-equal makes more sense in an example.

As odd as it seems, the feature that you are asking for is not available. However, there is a way to make use of the context that can help you.  First of all, it is still good to set a collection or collection scope so that we minimize the sample set to analyze the context path.

The approach is to use xPath and xQuery on the context as a filter.

Below is a working sample for Query Console.  Please not the ';' in the code as it is a multi-statement sample.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $_ := xdmp:document-insert("/llamas/Jalliue.xml", <llama><name>Jalliue</name></llama>, map:new()=>map:with("collections", ("llama", "include")))
let $_ := xdmp:document-insert("/llamas/Sven.xml", <llama><name>Sven</name></llama>, map:new()=>map:with("collections", ("llama", "exclude")))
return ();



let $docs := (fn:doc("/llamas/Jalliue.xml"), fn:doc("/llamas/Sven.xml"))

let $template := 
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <description>llama list</description>
  <context>/llama[xdmp:node-collections(.) != "exclude"]</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>llama</schema-name>
      <view-name>list</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>name</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>name</val>
        </column>
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>

return tde:node-data-extract($docs, $template)
```

The result shows that both documents were considered, but only the one with the collection "include" is parsed.

```
{
  "/llamas/Jalliue.xml": [
    {
      "row": {
      "schema": "llama", 
      "view": "list", 
      "data": {
        "rownum": "1", 
        "name": "Jalliue"
        }
      }
    }
  ], 
  "/llamas/Sven.xml": []
}
```